# Convert Json Object to Comma Separated

Tags: php, json

I need help to separated my JSON object with the comma. The JSON is converted from looping array PHP.
this is JSON:

```
 {
    "sales_invoice": {
        "transaction_date": "2016-11-14", 
    }
} {
    "sales_invoice": {
        "transaction_date": "2016-11-16", 
    }
}
```

I need to separate that JSON with a comma.

```
{  
    "sales_invoices": 
  [
    {
      "sales_invoice": {
         "transaction_date": "2016-11-14",
    }}, 
   {
     "sales_invoice": {
        "transaction_date": "2016-11-16",
    }} 
  ]
}
```

Comment: That first one is not a valid json document. It's two unrelated json objects. Can you provide some code? See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: JSON formatted, always provide not working code, whatever you've have tried so far...